# Handlebars expression inside {{#each}}

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I building my next portfolio site. How I can place handlebars expressions inside an `#each` loop? This is an express application generated by express-generator. I'm using the `express-handlebars` NPM package:

`views/home.hbs`:

```
{{#each images}}
  <li><img src="{{imagesFolder}}{{this}}.jpg" alt=""></li>
{{/each}}
```

`routes/home.js`:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home', {
    layout: 'main',
    centering: true,
    titleShown: false,
    title: 'Hi!',
    description: 'Home page',
    keywords: 'wedding,photography,film',
    bodyClass: 'horizontal',
    imagesFolder: '\/portfolio\/weddings\/',
    images: [
      'image-1',
      'image-2',
      'image-3'
    ]
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

What should return:

```
<li><img src="/portfolio/weddings/image-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="/portfolio/weddings/image-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="/portfolio/weddings/image-3.jpg" alt=""></li>
```

But what it's returning:

```
<li><img src="image-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="image-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="image-3.jpg" alt=""></li>
```

Worked fine until I moved the `/portfolio/weddings/` folder structure from the .hbs file into the router.

Repo: https://github.com/DJviolin/horgalleryNode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need access to parent's property `imagesFolder`:

```
{{#each images}}
  <li><img src="{{../imagesFolder}}{{this}}.jpg" alt=""></li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank You! Works flawlessly!